# Mysql database table structure

Tags: mysql

I currently busy with a project that I want to do for my second year at college... The project is all about users and contacts, each user can have many contacts and many contacts can belong to many users, since I see it as a many to many relationship I want to create a user_contact table. The relationship between a user and a contact can either be a friend,work college or family member..the relationship can also be either passive or active state.. I also want to keep track of who last edited the record of a contact and on what date by a certain user

The system will be used internally in a certain company and the system is all about showing the relationship that users have with contacts outside the company for example john is searching for pam that works for cola cola and he sees that phil that works with him also knows pam as a friend and the relationship is in a active state..

My current table structure:

```
//User table

user_id | username|password|fname|lname|email

//Contact_table
contact_id|fname|lname|contactnumber|email|lastedited|editdate

//User_contact table
id|user_id|contact_id|relationship_type|relationship_state
```

Since I'm new to the mysql environment my question is I'm I going the right way about it...Any advise will be very helpful..

And how do I link the user id from user table to the user id in the user_contact table and the same for the contact id ??

Comment: Looks pretty good. However setting relationship types apart would allow for expansion

Comment: What happens if user a and b is both linked to contact 1 (with contact number 1234) but then user a changes his contact number to 1235... Not that the design is not right, but try to consider all possible relation changes also?

Comment: Hi, thanx for the comment, that's way I want to keep track of which user makes the last change to a contact record so lets say for example,john and phil works for the same company ,so if you click on john you will see all the contacts that he knows like pam and the same with phil. If you view the contact pam you'll see all her information and that john did make the last change to her record so john will be held responsible for the wrong information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edition of the contact should be a separate table to avoid partial dependance. 
Also, its better to put people to people, so you dont need contacts table
If you are going to use InnoDB you should establish foreign key restrains to link person_id from contacts and editions tables to the persons table.
Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE editions (
edit_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
contact_id INT,
editor_id INT,
editdate DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES contacts(contact_id),
FOREIGN KEY (editor_id) REFERENCES users(person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE contacts (
person_id INT,
contact_id INT,
relationship_type ENUM("friend", "work", "family"),
relationship_state CHAR(1),
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons(person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES persons(person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE persons (
person_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(15),
lname VARCHAR(25),
email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
contactnumber VARCHAR(15)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "link" you want to make is called a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html), and can be declared in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You may also want to remove the redundant `id` from the `User_Contact` table and declare the relationship itself the primary key. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE User_Contact(
  user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `User`(user_id),
  contact_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `Contact`(contact_id),
  -- other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, contact_id)
);
```

This tells the DBMS that `user_id`s in `User_Contact` come from `User`. In MySQL, whether these constraints are actually enforced depends on [which storage engine you've chosen](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html). *InnoDB* enforces them; *MyIASM* does not.

Comment: Additionally, I am not sure you require a separate `id` in the user_contact table. You could create a composite primary key consisting of `user_id` & `contact_id`, since a user will have a unique relationship with a contact.

Comment: @Antimony This is an ongoing holy war among DB people, but I tend to agree with you. I'll update the answer to include that suggestion.